# jgrowl for ruby on rails how to?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey im looking for a step by step on how to implement jgrowl flash notifications into my rails application.  Im still very new to ruby on rails....

In my application.html.erb i have some code in there to handle all my flash messages

```
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, value, id: 'add-regular') %>
  <% end %>
```

is there some way i can just add the jgrowl effect to that code?  I am using DEVISE for authentication.  Would i need to make custom controllers to handle my flash notifications with jGrowL?

I want it to handle all my error/flash/success messages

Comment: also if you guys know of a good tutorial on this that would be great as well

Comment: should i use the gem?  or just the jquery file?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow below code I have implemented jgrowl in my app that was excellent,

```
      <%= msgs = ""
      flash.each do |n,m| 
        msgs += "$.jGrowl('hello');"
      end

      if msgs.size > 0
        content_tag :script , "$(document).ready(function() { #{ msgs} });" , :type => "text/javascript"
      end %>
```